# Initialize exception with stacktrace from another exception?

Tags: java, exception, client-server, stack-trace

I have client-server system. They communicate via RMI, so serialization/deserialization is involved. Server sends a response to client upon a request. If exception occurs it is set in the response.

However, if some exception occurs at the server and the client does not know about it. So I need to wrap the original exception but to keep the stacktrace for debug purposes. Is there more elegant solution?

```
//response from server to client
class Response {
    private MyException e;

    public void set(MyException e) {
       this.e = e;
    }
}

//some other code
catch (MyException e) {
   response.set(e);      
} catch (Exception e) {
   //could be exception which does not exist at client
   //so I can not just set because it would cause ClassNotFoundException at client
   response.set(new MyException(e.getMessage() + ": " + e.getStackTrace()));   
}
```

It seems that API supports only setting `cause` which I cannot because of the problem abovementioned. Can I set a stacktrace from another exception without setting cause?

Comment: I would play with implementing an exception, that would fill the stack trace from cause, but remove the cause itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the method [setStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#setStackTrace-java.lang.StackTraceElement%3aA-), for example:

```
Throwable originalException = ...;
Throwable clientException = ...;
clientException.setStackTrace(originalException.getStackTrace());
```

The stacktrace elements themselves appear to consist of strings only, so this should not present a problem for the client which does not know about special server classes.