# Sending serialized exception to client with custom exception stacktrace

Tags: java

This might be a noob question so please bear with me. I am trying to send an exception over wire to client by serializing it but still retaining the cause exception stacktrace. Client might not have that cause exception class. I am using `setStackTrace` method but it's puzzling me why it's not working.

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException(final String message, final StackTraceElement[] stackTrace) {
         super(message);

        this.setStackTrace(stackTrace);
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    MyExceptione = new MyException("Failure", new Exception("Original Exception").getStackTrace());
    throw e;
}
```

This prints the following. Root cause stacktrace is missing.

```
Exception in thread "main" pkg.MyException: Failure
at pkg.MyException.main(MyException.java:20)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Similar question: [Initialize exception with stacktrace from another exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140634/initialize-exception-with-stacktrace-from-another-exception) where it tells about same scenario.

Comment: Is your motivation to advise the client? Does the client need the specifics of the trace? Are you trying to debug?

Comment: i'm not necessarily recommending this, but you can override `fillInStackTrace()` to do nothing.

Comment: @robbmj, It is mainly for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

One technique i have used to solve this problem is to create a special (obviously Serializable) "passthrough" exception (similar to your MyException).  this exception takes the stack trace, message, *and class name* of the original exception.  it overrides the `toString()` method to print the *original* class name in place of the passthrough exception's class name.  the important bit (as you have noticed), is that *you can't throw this exception after you create it*.  instead, use a different, shared class with the passthrough exception as the "cause" which is thrown to the client side.  note that a "robust" implementation of the passthrough exception should iterate through and replace the *entire cause chain* of the original exception.

Basic example (where ServerException and PassthroughException are known to the client):

```
public class PassthroughException extends RuntimeException {
   private final String _originalName;

   public PassthroughException(Throwable t) {
       super(t.getMessage(), passthrough(t.getCause()));
       _originalName = t.getClass().getName();
       setStackTrace(t.getStackTrace());
   }

   public String toString() {
       String msg = getMessage();
       return _originalName + ((msg != null) ? (": " + msg) : "");
   }

   private static Throwable passthrough(Throwable t) {
     return ((t != null) ? new PassthroughException(t) : null);
   }
}

try {
  // ... do some stuff on server ...
} catch(Throwable t) {
  throw new ServerException(new PassthroughException(t));
}
```